# Java Servlet: Session cookie is null for subsequent requests

Tags: java, servlets, session-cookies

I am trying to set an attribute to session cookie and use that attribute for subsequent requests (after the very first request). Following is my code. Here I am using `check` variable to check the functionality of the code. For the very first request, it should give me "init" and "original" for subsequent requests. But, I am getting "init" as the output for all requests. What is the reason for this issue?

```
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest reqest, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    HttpSession ssn = reqest.getSession();
    reqest.getSession(true);
    String check="original";
    if(ssn.getAttribute("currentQuestion")==null){
        check="init";
        ssn.setAttribute("currentQuestion","0");
    }
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.getWriter().println(check);
}
```

I am using folloeing AJAX client to send requests

```
function submitAnswer() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://example.com:8080/Simple/hello?username=malintha", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the servlet? Are you sure you're passing a session cookie?

Comment: There seems to be some terminology confusion. The server side session is not a "session cookie".

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Added my client code

Comment: Are you sending that AJAX request from within a browser? Or from NodeJS or something? Might also be worth checking if you have a `JSESSIONID` cookie coming in (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies()).

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes, within the browser

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your code is fine.  However, I notice you are calling getSession twice. This is not necessary.  Try removing the second getSession(true) call.

Also, make sure you use an external browser such as Chrome or Firefox instead of the browser built into eclipse.